# Problems with interpretation in zeroinflated models in R

Tags: interaction, zero-inflation

My response variable is number of Fishing cat scats and I am using a zero-inflated poisson regression model to see the effect of the predictor variables on habitat use of Fishing
cats. The predictor variables are Reed area, Vegetation Area and Agricultural area.

Now, before using the GLM, I used scatterplots to see what the trends are between the response variable and each predictor variable based on my data and in it I saw that Fishing cats are negatively impacted by increase in agricultural area. However, the GLM is showing a positive correlation of Fishing cats with Agricultural area which is significant. However, when I take Agricultural area alone in the GLM, it shows an insignificant negative correlation. I do not know what to interpret out of this. I tried interactions also thinking that interaction with one of the predictors might have a positive effect on Agricultural area. Here is what it looks like:

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = No_FC ~ Reed_area + Veg_area * Agril_area)

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-1.20907 -0.37197 -0.29263 -0.23930  6.97929

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                    Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)         -2.64186    0.98692 -2.6769 0.0074315 **
Reed_area            1.88105    0.52355  3.5928 0.0003271 ***
Veg_area             2.38728    0.64685  3.6906 0.0002237 ***
Agril_area           2.05895    0.71096  2.8960 0.0037791 **
Veg_area:Agril_area -1.55241    0.86485 -1.7950 0.0726528 .

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)         -0.68988    1.82259 -0.3785   0.7050
Reed_area           -0.72748    1.00656 -0.7227   0.4698
Veg_area             0.39630    1.34636  0.2944   0.7685
Agril_area           1.64785    1.15165  1.4309   0.1525
Veg_area:Agril_area  0.50427    1.30075  0.3877   0.6983
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 17
Log-likelihood: -134.02 on 10 Df.
```

It shows that the interaction term is also negatively affecting Fishing
cat habitat use. Here is what it looks like when I take Agricultural area
alone.

```
fishing_cat.glm <- zeroinfl(No_FC~Agril_area)
> summary(fishing_cat.glm)

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = No_FC ~ Agril_area)

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
-0.68839 -0.43312 -0.31080 -0.20735  8.16459

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.85358    0.18532  4.6059 4.107e-06 ***
Agril_area  -0.31194    0.26974 -1.1565    0.2475

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  0.16657    0.34396  0.4843 0.628200
Agril_area   1.30806    0.40498  3.2299 0.001238 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 16
Log-likelihood: -146.93 on 4 Df
```

Could you kindly give me some direction as to how I can circumnavigate
this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you add variables to a regression model (whether it is a ZIP or any other kind) you are controlling for them. So, with reed_area and veg_area and the interaction held constant, agril_area has a positive effect on fishing cat scats (both parts of the model: So, more likely not to be 0 and more likely to be higher if it is not 0).

When you don't control for those variables, agril_area has a positive effect on the zero-inflation part but a negative effect on the count part (more likely not to be 0 but likely to be smaller when it is not 0). But the effect on the count part is not significant.

Comment: thank you peter. can you explain  a little more clearly what you mean by this -  more likely not to be 0 and more likely to be higher if it is not 0 ?

Comment: The ZIP model has two components: One to say "Will the DV be 0 or > 0?" and the other to say "Given that it is not 0, how big will it be?"

Comment: @peter.....thank you again.....but i still have problems understanding......i am a novice in stats, sry.......what is DV?......"gievn that it is not 0"........what does it signify?

Comment: DV = dependent variable. If you are really a novice in stats, then you may need to hire a consultant. These models are not simple.